# frida how to create multiple interceptors in one script

Tags: javascript, python, frida

I want to intercept two addresses 0x7FFCF5D50000,0x7FFCF7C99B00 in one script.

But the example can only have 1 script and 1 interceptor, and attach can only be %s

```py
script = session.create_script(""" 
Interceptor.attach(ptr("%s"), {
    onEnter: function(args) {
    }
});
""" % int(sys.argv[1], 16))
```

I tried changing the script to the following, which I think should work, but it doesn't.

```py
script = session.create_script(""" 
Interceptor.attach(ptr("0x7FFCF5D50000"), {
    onEnter: function(args) {
    }
});
""" % int(sys.argv[1], 16))
error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\1.py", line 5, in <module>
    script = session.create_script("""
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

My purpose is like this, because the data of the two addresses are related, I don't really want to write them separately. Or I want to know if a script can support multiple interceptors.

```py
script = session.create_script("""
var g_db_path = "";
Interceptor.attach(ptr("0x7FFCF5D50000"), { 
    onEnter(args){
    }
});
Interceptor.attach(ptr("0x7FFCF7C99B00"), {
    onEnter(args){
    }
});
""" % int(sys.argv[1], 16))
```

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

The command `session.create_script(...)` just expects a JavaScript file content as parameter. This means you can simply create multiple interceptor one after another as well as define JavaScript functions variables and so on. I have scripts with up to 20 interceptors and more.

```
script = session.create_script("""
Interceptor.attach(ptr('0x7FFCF5D50000'), { 
    onEnter(args){
    }
});
Interceptor.attach(ptr('0x7FFCF7C99B00'), {
    onEnter(args){
    }
});
```

But in my opinion I would recommend to create an external script file and load it instead of writing the JavaScript code "inline". That has the advantage that you can use an editor that supports code formatting highlighting as well as code completion and similar functions. Also in case of code problems (forgotten brackets and so on) you can get the line number in the error message and directly jump to the error line. For larger scripts this is really helpful:

```
with open('frida_script.js', 'r') as f:
    source = f.read()

session.create_script(source, name='frida_script.js')
```